# Spring Security 3.1 intercept urls

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have my configuration of intercept url like

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/admission/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMISSIONER')" />              
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/subdean/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUBDEAN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/referent/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_REFERENT')" />                   
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/index.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_REFERENT, ROLE_SUBDEAN')" />    
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_OMNI_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

But now I have a problem that it is possible to acces url of my application, for example MY_APPLICATION/PririzMaven/secure/admin/updateRole.xhtml with role ROLE_ADMISSIONER, url ..../secure/subdean/* with this same role and so on... but it should by banned to this user.

Do you know where could be a problemme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `PririzMaven` is the context path of your application, `/secure/admin/updateRole.xhtml` will be matched by the path `/**` and hence will be accessible to all authenticated users. You have no rule for `/secure/admin`. Note also that a single '*' does not match subpaths. For example, you should use `/secure/admin/**` to match everything under this path.

You should also enable debug logging and check how the rules are being applied - you should see the matchers being called against the incoming request URL and will see what is being compared and what is being matched against.

Finally, it's worth adding `<security:debug />` at the top of your application context file, which will add other useful debugging information on request handling in a more human-readable format.